# Get mod-rewrite title after $_GET

Tags: php, mod-rewrite, get

I currently use this mod-rewrite

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ post.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ post.php?id=$1 [L]
```

which allows me to add on the post title in the url after `$_GET['id]`

```
http://foo.com/246/clouds
```

*domain / get / title*

How can I get/fetch/return the title part from the url so to be able to use it inside the `<title></title>` tags?

I know how to get the `$_GET['id']`

```
$pid = (isset($_GET['id']) ? 'foo : Page - ' . $_GET['id'] : '');
```

which returns

```
foo : Page - 246
```

as the page title but would really like to have

```
foo : clouds
```

Comment: It really surprises me that no one else has suggested this; Turn it into a oneliner: `RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/?$ post.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]`. The last `/?` means `/` repeated 0 or 1 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the redirection rules:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ post.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ post.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

Then you simply use `$_GET['title']` to retrieve the title.

Hope that helped!

Comment: I should have known this, must be having one of those days lol, thx Felix

Answer (score 1):

You dont acctually need to pass anything in the rewrite eg adding `title=$2` you can access `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` which will contain `/246/clouds` then you can explode that by `/` and then access the second key value.

```
$url_parts = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
print_r($url_parts);
```

Comment: This is exactly what I just did before reading your post, I didn't want to mess with the mod-rewrite more a case of turning the title part of url into a variable somehow, though the mod-rewrite is probably the better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Updated your RewriteRule to the 2. parameter

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)$ post.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ post.php?id=$1&title=$2 [L]
```

and

```
print_r($_GET["title"]);
```